# How can i correct  hiding a list from a group of html list?

Tags: jquery, html

In my view

```
<ul>
<li id="list">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="grid-table08" id="table1">
<tbody>
<tr><td><img src="../../Content/Images/downarrow.gif" title="Hide Details" class="hide">
</td></tr>

<tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="15" nowrap="nowrap">
Hii good morning
</td>
<tr>
</table>
</li>

<li>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="grid-table08" id="table1">
<tbody>
<tr><td><img src="../../Content/Images/downarrow.gif" title="Hide Details"  class="hide">
</td></tr>

<tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="15" nowrap="nowrap">
Hii good evening
</td>
<tr>
</table>
</li>

</ul>
```

There are total 10 li when i click the image with id hide i need to hide the particular li

my script as follows

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $(".hide").live("click", function () {

       $(".hide").closest("li").hide("slow");


    });

});
```

but its not working anyone pls help me

Comment: Why do you use `#li` (as if it was an ID) instead of just selecting via `.closest('li')`? Also you are using `hide` as an ID in your HTML and as a class (see the `.`) in the JavaScript.

Comment: HTML tag ID must be unique, you are using the ID="list" multiple time.  Try fixing that and see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your img tags has an ID="hide" instead of CLASS="hide".

```
WRONG:  <img src="../../Content/Images/downarrow.gif" title="Hide Details" id="hide"> 
GOOD:   <img src="../../Content/Images/downarrow.gif" title="Hide Details" class="hide"> 

$(".hide") - this one selects all elements with class="hide"
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, you have multiple LI tags with the same ID="list": `<li id="list">`
You have to use a class: `<li class="list">`

The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one.

**SOLUTION:**

```
<li class="list"> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="grid-table08" id="table1"> 
<tbody> 
<tr><td><img src="../../Content/Images/downarrow.gif" title="Hide Details" class="hide"> 
</td></tr> 

<tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="15" nowrap="nowrap"> 
Hii good morning 
</td> 
<tr> 
</table> 
</li> 

<li class="list"> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="grid-table08" id="table1"> 
<tbody> 
<tr><td><img src="../../Content/Images/downarrow.gif" title="Hide Details" class="hide"> 
</td></tr> 

<tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="15" nowrap="nowrap"> 
Hii good evening 
</td> 
<tr> 
</table> 
</li> 

</ul>
```

and

```
$(function () {  
    $(".hide").live("click", function () {  
        $(this).parents("li.list:first").hide("slow");  
    });  
});
```

Try the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/RtXn9/

Comment: but in li i already used a class named "users" that i not mentioned above before

Comment: hi by giving id="list" to li and change $(this).parents("li#list:first").hide("slow"); it works great

Comment: I don't see any "users" class. Please modify your question to reflect what do you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use unique id for more than one element ..change id="hide" to class="hide" in your HTML

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    

        $(".hide").live("click", function () {    
           $(this).parents().find('li').hide('slow');   

        });    

    });
```

Comment: so you want to hide only the image ?

Comment: Now only the parent li will hide